# Sync Folder contents into Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

How can I sync folder contents into Ubuntu One without manually copying/pasting it? Let's say I want to sync my /var/www into the Ubuntu One, how can I do that? Is there a folder mirroring app for Ubuntu 11.10? Thanks!

Comment: Its already in Ubuntu, isn't it? Try right-clicking the folder and you'll find an "Ubuntu One" menu option...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sync a folder outside your home directory with Ubuntu One directly. However, if you're looking to save the contents of (say) /var/www into Ubuntu One in order to back it up, and you're using Ubuntu, then please have a look at Déjà Dup, which you can install from Software Centre; it allows you to back up any folders you want to Ubuntu One and then later restore them if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Open up terminal and run:

```
u1sdtool --subscribe-folder="YOUR FOLDER LOCATION"
```

This should subscribe Ubuntu One to the folder and synchronize it.